# Facebook: How to separate debug and prod mode events?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I'm using the Facebook SDK to track ads mobile install and followed this tutorial: [mobile ads install](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/)

So far, events in **DashBoard** / **Insight** are not **separated** for **debug** / **prod** mode.

Do I have to create 2 appIDs to separate the debug and prod events in DashBoard/Insight ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is to you use the `DEBUG` preprocessor macro (or create a new one if needed), to set the correct Facebook's appId for you build. You can use the method `FBSettings setDefaultAppID:` from Facebook SDK to reach this, without hardcode the appId in the Info.plist.

Let me write a simple example:

```
// 1 - Set the app id on compile time, based in macro you choosed
#if DEBUG
  kFacebookAppID = @"your app id for debug";
#else
  kFacebookAppID = @"your app id for production";
#endif


// After then, you can set the id in your app delegate initialization
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:kFacebookAppID];
```

I hope this help you.